# queryset tag on template

Tags: django, templates, django-queryset

I would show the users list, I return it by:

```
    active_sessions = Session.objects.filter(expire_date__gte=timezone.now())
    user_id_list = []
    user_name_list = []
    tot_active_sessions = active_sessions.count()
    for session in active_sessions:
        data = session.get_decoded()
        user_id_list.append(data.get('_auth_user_id', None))
    for k in user_id_list:
        user_name_list.append(User.objects.filter(id__in=k))
    if tot_active_sessions > _sessions_limit :
        logout(request)
        return  render(request, 'page/users.html',  context={'user_name_list': user_name_list})
```

in my template 'page/users.html':

```
{% for username in user_name_list %}
      {{ username }}
{% endfor %}
```

with the following result:

```
•<QuerySet [<User: guest2>]>
•<QuerySet [<User: guest1>]>
```

How can I obtain only:

```
•guest2
•guest1
```

In others situations I didn't see the queryset tag on my template, I haven't idea about this result..

Comment: I will need to see your complete views(how you are getting `user_name_list`) and probably your models too. I have few clues whats wrong but I can't be sure unless I see your whole code.

Comment: Please share the view that constructed the `user_name_list`. I have the idea that you used `.filter(..)` in a `for` loop or list comprehension.

Comment: Added the short code, It's in the middleware file

Comment: change the orm query from filter to get, that shuld solve the issue

Comment: for k in user_id_list:
        user_name_list.append(User.objects.get(id__in=k))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view itself produces a list of `QuerySet`s, not a list of `User`s, this is due to the:

```
for k in user_id_list:
    user_name_list.append(User.objects.filter(id__in=k))
```

You here thus include a *filtered* `QuerySet`, not a `User` object itself.

Nevertheless, your code in the view is rather complicated, and can be improved both in readability, and efficiency:

```
active_sessions = Session.objects.filter(expire_date__gte=timezone.now())
user_list = User.objects.filter(
    id__in=[session.get_decoded().get('_auth_user_id', None) for session in active_sessions]
)
tot_active_sessions = active_sessions.count()
if tot_active_sessions > _sessions_limit:
    logout(request)
    return  render(request, 'page/users.html',  context={'user_name_list': user_list })
```

Here we thus construct a *single* `QuerySet` that contains all the users with active sessions, and we render that list, we do not make a `list` of `QuerySet`s. This will thus enumerate over users, you can also obtain the `username` values directly, with:

```
active_sessions = Session.objects.filter(expire_date__gte=timezone.now())
user_list = User.objects.filter(
    id__in=[session.get_decoded().get('_auth_user_id', None) for session in active_sessions]
).values_list('username', flat=True)
tot_active_sessions = active_sessions.count()
if tot_active_sessions > _sessions_limit:
    logout(request)
    return  render(request, 'page/users.html',  context={'user_name_list': user_list })
```

**EDIT**: In case we want to list users multiple times, if a user has multiple open sessions, we can still do this with a single database query, and then "unfold" the results in a list, like:

```
active_sessions = Session.objects.filter(expire_date__gte=timezone.now())
uids=[session.get_decoded().get('_auth_user_id', None) for session in active_sessions]
tot_active_sessions = active_sessions.count()
if tot_active_sessions > _sessions_limit:
    user_dict = dict(
        User.objects.filter(
        id__in=uids
    ).values_list('id', 'username'))
    user_list = [user_dict.get(_id) for _id in uids]
    logout(request)
    return  render(request, 'page/users.html',  context={'user_name_list': user_list })
```

Comment: filter returns a new queryset, all he needs is a first value from it. get() shuld do the trick.

Comment: @RyuCoder: but here we have a *list* of `.get(..)`s, which is inefficient, since it would result in *O(n)* queries, instead of a simple `QuerySet` that contains *all* the users we want. If you look at the template, you notice we *iterate* over the `user_name_list`, so we do not want to query the elements separately, we want to fetch these "in bulk". Since otherwise this will take some time. Another advantage is that here we do not "make the query" in case `tot_active_sessions <= _session_limit`.

Comment: @RyuCoder: notice that we do *not* `user_list.append(..)`, but `user_list = User.objects.filter(...)`.

Comment: @WillemVanOsem Right, this one is better :)

Comment: I checked that it doesn't return the "multi" username but only single

Comment: @Mixo: no, indeed. Is that a requirement? can you edit your question with the specifications you want?

Comment: Yes I need the complete users list

Comment: @Mixo: but you get the complete user list, but a list that contains two or more sessions is listed *once*.

Comment: I' m sorry but i didn't understand what u mean @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @Mixo: there is a one-to-many relation between `User`s, and `Session`s....

Comment: Ok ,  how can I plot all sessions ? I need to show all the users online...thank u

Comment: @Mixo: you show *all* users online, but you do not show these *multiple* times in case a user has multiple active sessions. With the last code fragment, you will show such users multiple times as well.